# Fourier transform $\hat{f}(\gamma)$ analytic in whole complex plane if $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^1)$ is compact?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, analyticity

How to show that Fourier transform $\hat{f}(\gamma)$ analytic in whole complex plane if $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^1)$ is compact?

Attempt: Since $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^1)$ we have that

$\hat{f}(\gamma)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)e^{-2\pi i y \gamma}dy$

is well defined. Because $f$ is bounded we have $f(y)\leq M$ for all $y$ and some constant $M$. Thus by the triangle inequality.

$\hat{f}(\gamma) \leq M\int_{-\infty}^\infty |e^{-2\pi i y \gamma}|dy \leq M\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy$.

But since the integral is diverging that did not seem to help as we want to show, for $\hat{f}(\gamma)$ to be analytic, that $\hat{f}(\gamma)$ can be represented as a e.g. convergent power series or that:

$
\hat{f}'(\gamma)=-2\pi i y\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)e^{-2\pi i y \gamma}dy
$

exists.

Comment: Apply definition of derivative and use DCT.

Comment: An $L^2$ function does not need to be bounded.

Comment: @geetha290krm I did not consider DCT=Discrete cosine transform but will look into that.

Comment: What do you mean by "$f$ is compact"? Does that mean "$f$ is bounded"?

Comment: @Severin Schraven ok but that is given as an assumption here. Maybe I miss something

Comment: @ Feng The question only refers to compact. It was my interpretation that it implies that $f$ is closed and bounded (I'm aware that does not always holds but I guess simplified)

Comment: Oh, I read compact support. I do not know what a compact function is supposed to be.

Comment: DCT is Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: Does compact mean bounded support ? If so you can use for instance the Morera theorem or calculate directly the derivative as suggested by geetha290krm.

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc question only refers to compact. Thank you will look into calculating the derivative directly

Comment: Then what do you mean by saying that $f$ is compact ?

Comment: The question is from a book and unfortunately I have no more information what the author intended but my guess is that it is the range of the function that is compact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not be "$f$ is compact" which has no meaning to my knowledge but "$f$ is compactly supported". Then the theorem is known as the Paley-Wiener theorem.

Let $K$ be the compact support of $f$. In this case indeed, $\hat f$ is bounded since the integral defining the Fourier transform is reduced to a bounded domain and by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$
\hat f(y) = \int_K f(x) \,e^{-2i\pi x\cdot y}\, \mathrm d x \leq \|f\|_{L^2} \,|K|^{1/2}
$$
More generally, taking $n$ derivatives and defining $R$ such that $K$ is included in the ball of size $R$,
$$
|(\hat f)^{(n)}(y)| = \left|\int_K (2\pi x)^n f(x) \,e^{-2i\pi x\cdot y}\, \mathrm d x\right|
\\
\leq (2\pi)^n \|f\|_{L^2} \left(\int_{-R}^R |x|^{2n} \,\mathrm d x\right)^{1/2}
\\
\leq \sqrt{\tfrac{2R}{2n+1}} (2\pi R)^n \|f\|_{L^2}
$$
from which you can easily prove the convergence of the Taylor series, and the convergence to $0$ of the remainder.